# JSON to angular select with ng-options

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, select, ng-options

I am attempting to get a JSON encoded response from an AJAX request into a select statement using angular ng-options. I do not have control of the PHP source of where the JSON response comes from.

The response is in the form:

```
{"A":"Col1","B":"Col2","C":"Col3","D":"Col4"}
```

I am using a simple select dropdown and need to populate the above JSON utilizing the index set as the value and the value set as the dropdown text. Example below.

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item for item in items">
```

Options should result in this:

```
<option value="A">Col1</option>  
<option value="B">Col2</option>
<option value="C">Col3</option>
...
```

I am unsure what I am missing for the format of the JSON response so it'll be used in the ng-options. I've tried all forms of the ng-options to no avail. I've also tried to format the response with json.parse, json.stringify, .eval(), etc.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the json_encoded array was a correct object when it hit the angular function, I was able to get this working just by keeping it an object and manipulating the ng-options with a key, value configuration. Code below.

`<select ng-options="k as v for (k, v) in cols"></select>`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgrohol/s11xd6uw/19/)

I referenced the post here: [ng-options with object data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392678/ng-options-with-object-data-source)

This worked out because I don't have control over the json encoded array coming to my controller but I needed to reference the key as the value for the options of the select instead of letting angular let it do its own thing with it.

Answer (score 0):

use the angular JSON parser build in function: `$scope.items = angular.fromJson(myJSON)`
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson

Comment: I tried that, but still having difficulty. I made a jsfiddle for where I currently am at. I am taking the object and creating an array then dumping it into the ng-options. I need to get the key as the value of the select option so I can have A, B, C, etc as the value. How can change the array to achieve this?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jgrohol/s11xd6uw/2/)