# AngularJs: How to bind a object with ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I have implemented a drop down where i m trying to populate my drop down from database using ng-options but when the data comes it comes in a object which don't have key or value as you can see in image below.I have tried to use ng options as:-
by using ng-option

```
<tr>
<td nowrap>Billing Method:</td>
<td>
<select id="listBillingMethod" data-ng-options="blngmthod as blngmthod for blngmthod in listBillingMethod"  ng-model="custom.listBillingMethod" style="width: 182px !important; height: 34px;"></select>
</td>
<td nowrap></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
```

If i am trying to do the same using ng-repeater it gives me results as i want,i.e my dropdown will populated up.My ng-repeater code:-

```
 <tr>
 <td nowrap>Billing Method:</td>
 <td>
 <select id="listBillingMethod" style="width: 182px !important; height: 34px;">
 <option value="0">--- Select an option ---</option>
 <option data-ng-repeat="blngmthod in listBillingMethod">{{blngmthod}}</option>
</select>
</td>
<td nowrap></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

My data comes in form of:-
[image: Data Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this fiddle you should really use ng-options if ur Data Object has no keys than modify it so it fits for the ng-options example

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2TKry/7/)

```
<form>        
    <select ng-model="group" 
        ng-options="o.value as o.label for o in myGroups"
        ng-change="tellUs()"/>       
</form>
```

Comment: I have seen you fiddle but there you know the name of key and value here i am getting my key or value as you can see in the above image.

Comment: ah i forget to include this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392678/ng-options-with-object-data-source this explains how to use ng-options, with a datasource

Comment: I have one more question how can i pass the index value on ng change to a function so that i can process further..Means i want to check the index of  my dropdown and than based upon its index my function will go to my API get the data accordingly and return the same.

Is there any way to set a default value with index 0 as Select Option or something..

Comment: i found this for your index problem http://jsfiddle.net/EyBVN/28/ with index.Of you can get the desired index of your object when that object is selected the binded scope.value is getting updated

Comment: in your example you could get index.Of blngmethod in your ng-change function this should work

Comment: but how do i pass this value to a function on ng-change like i want to use index value as listselectedindexchnage() and then want to use that index value for a condition as if(list.index=1) than somthing...

Comment: ng-change="listselectedindexchnage( index.Of(item))" so every time it changes you get the index of the object currently selected and in the change function you ca do your condition and just remove the option tag so you have only <select ng-options="" ng-model=""></select>  then you should have a default value if you have set ng-model